# Google Maps in Phonegap APP - only displays after deleting jquery.min.js

Tags: google-maps, cordova

Sorry for my bad english, but i´m from Austria ;)

I have an interesting problem, don´t know why this happens:

I want to show a google map on a sub-site of my web app. (it should become a native app with phonegap build.)

If if have
`<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
in my HTML5 Web-App Code, my Google-Map doesn´t display...

If i delete this part of source it shows the google-map, but my complete app-design is "over board".

I don´t know what i can try? I could only find that this part of source makes the difference.

thanks for help!

Best regards
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

Not able to help much without see the structure of your code. Here is a link to an existing project that uses phonegap and google maps. [phonegap google maps](http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/)